# Inject html tags <ul></ul> before and after my <li></li> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to populate a jQuery dialog dynamically with data. The code below works but the beginning and ending html tags `<ul></ul>` are both inserted before the data (`<li>...</li>`) and not before and after as needed.

```
var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');

dialog.empty();
dialog.append('<ul>');

$.each(obj.data, function (i, filePath) 
{
    dialog.append('<li>' + filePath + '</li>');
});

dialog.append("</ul>");
```

Any idea how to proceed?

What I have now:

```
    dialog[0].innerHTML "<ul></ul><li>...</li><li>...</li>"
```

What I need:

```
    dialog[0].innerHTML "<ul><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul>"
```

Comment: Try appending to the <ul> instead of appending to the div itself. check jQuery.find() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending the content to div, you should find ul element inside it and then append the content in it. Like this:

```
$.each(obj.data, function (i, filePath){
   dialog.find('ul').append('<li>' + filePath + '</li>');
});
```